# Dual boot, two disks and poweroff unused disk?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, power-supply

I have set up my desktop from scratch as following:

- MSI B85M-P33 motherboard
- Crucial Sport 4GB installed RAM, will be expanded soon to at least 8GB
- Coolermaster N200 case
- Coolermaster  G450M psu
- Intel Pentium G3420

this as a side note, which is likely to know for a possible answer...

I have installed two 2.5 HDD, one with Win7, the other one with Ubuntu 14.04LTS

I configured it this way so they could have each an entire disk. Because the way Windows and Ubuntu partitions, read and writes to disks is slightly different. Dual boot on one disk is excluded thus.

Q: Is it possible to poweroff the disk containing the unused OS?

Comment: updated, simplified the question...

Comment: I don't think there are that many options for flagging as too broad? I'm just looking for a solution in hardware or software direction? And looking for people who actually already accomplished this.

Comment: I would like to have question reopened because I've found a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are mobile racks for 2.5 sata disks you can build in a 3.5 drive bay.

These also have an on/off switch, so putting the harddisk in here, I should be able to poweroff the disk which isn't loaded. Although if this is safe or not, this is the solution which will work for now.